# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in C:\xampp\htdocs\eifel\title_bar.php on line 4

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

I have a development server for PHP that runs XAMPP. The problem that I have is a parse error. The exact parse error that XAMPP is giving is:

"Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in C:\xampp\htdocs\eifel\title_bar.php on line 4"

I don't see any missing curly braces, nor semi-colons; but there is something that Notepad++ is giving me. There are wavy red lines under the file extension '.php'. The code for the class is below:

**The code for the 'title_bar.php' class:**

```
<div>
<?php
if(loggedin()){
        <a href='index.php'>Home</a>
        <a href='messages.php'>Messages</a>
        <a href='logout.php'>Log Out</a>
}else{
        echo "Not Logged In";
}
}
<a href='index.php'>Home</a>
<a href='login.php'>Login</a>
<a href='register.php'>Register</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Well that's not PHP.  You have PHP and HTML and only PHP code should be between `<?php` and `?>` tags:

```
<?php
if(loggedin()){
        ?>
        <a href='index.php'>Home</a>
        <a href='messages.php'>Messages</a>
        <a href='logout.php'>Log Out</a>
        <?php
}else{
    echo "Not Logged In";
}
?>
<a href='index.php'>Home</a>
<a href='login.php'>Login</a>
<a href='register.php'>Register</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Or similar to what has already been said, you could use:

```
<div>
<?php
if(loggedin()){
        echo "<a href='index.php'>Home</a>
        <a href='messages.php'>Messages</a>
        <a href='logout.php'>Log Out</a>";
}else{
        echo "Not Logged In";

        echo "<a href='index.php'>Home</a>
        <a href='login.php'>Login</a>
        <a href='register.php'>Register</a>";
}
?>
</div>
```

Make sure you echo or print any HTML elements in PHP otherwise you will get errors as HTML is not PHP.